# member.timeout() is not a function discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a system auto timeouting people who talks bad I did word array everything everything looks good but the timeout function is a problem

```
client.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {
client.channels.fetch('1178750152991838209')
.then(channel=> channel.send(`The message : "${messageDelete.content}" by ${messageDelete.author} was deleted. Their ID is ${messageDelete.author.id}. And they are muted for 5 minutes if this is repeated 5 times more ban him!`))
const member = messageDelete.author.id
member.timeout(60 * 5 * 1000)
```

});

Comment: `member` is just an id at the moment. `const member = messageDelete.author.id` should be `const member = messageDelete.author` only.

Comment: still timeout is not a function error

Comment: Hm, my bad. `author` is a `User`, not a `GuildMember`. So, `const member = messageDelete.author.id` should be `const { member } = messageDelete`.

Answer (score 1):

`.timeout()` method has implemented in `GuildMember` class. so,

```js
client.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {
  client.channels.fetch('1178750152991838209')
    .then(channel=> channel.send(`The message : "${messageDelete.content}" by ${messageDelete.author} was deleted. Their ID is ${messageDelete.author.id}. And they are muted for 5 minutes if this is repeated 5 times more ban him!`))
  const member = messageDelete.member
  member.timeout(60 * 5 * 1000)
});
```